# What is an alternative to \thanks for an author's footnote?

Tags: footnotes, titles, titling

I wonder what besides `\thanks` can be used for author's footnote.
The problem is that when I have two different titles with two different authors and two different `\thanks`, the second footnote shows both of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\begin{document}
\title{title1}
\author{someone1 \thanks{hi@email.com}}
\maketitle
\newpage
\title{title2}
\author{someone2 \thanks{bye@email.com}}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the command `\emptythanks` to clear the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\begin{document}
\title{title1}
\author{someone1 \thanks{hi@email.com}}
\maketitle
\newpage
\emptythanks
\title{title2}
\author{someone2 \thanks{bye@email.com}} 

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]